# Stuck on a Java instruction

Tags: java

Question:

The commands should be passed in to the program as a file with one instruction per line. The English instructions are in the file commands in english.txt and the Spanish instructions are in the file commands in spanish.txt. You call the program by the passing in the instructions as follows:

```
java ConsoleRobot < commands_in_english.txt
```

or

```
java ConsoleRobot < commands_in_spanish.txt
```

I don't get what the question is asking? Does it want me to have the commands I enter to go to the english text file or does it want me to have all my commands stored in the english text file?

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/4ewl3o7oh/) is a link to the full question. I got all of it except the last part. [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/consolerobot_1) is a link to my Java file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConsoleRobot extends SmarterRobot {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        World yard = new World();

        SmarterRobot ringo = new SmarterRobot();
        yard.add(ringo,5,4);

        yard.addBeeper(5,9);
        yard.addBeeper(4,5);

        yard.addBeeper(9,4);
        yard.addBeeper(9,5);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a command: | Introduzca un comando:");
        String command = scan.nextLine();
        command = command.toLowerCase();

        while (!command.equals("stop") && !command.equals("detener")) {

            if ( command.equals("forward") || command.equals("adelante")) {
                System.out.println("How far should the robot move?"); 
                int input = scan.nextInt();  
                ringo.moveNumOfTimes(input);

            } else if ( command.equals("right") || command.equals("derecha"))
                ringo.turnRight();
            else if ( command.equals("left") || command.equals("izquierda")
                ringo.turnLeft();
            else if ( command.equals("collect") || command.equals("recoger"))
                ringo.pickBeeper();
            else if ( command.equals("drop") || command.equals("soltar"))
                ringo.putBeeper();


            System.out.println("Enter a command: | Introduzca un comando:");
            command = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished | Terminado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and make a [mcve].

Comment: It is saying that the commands to issue the robot should be in `commands_in_english.txt`. This way you don't have to type them in manually.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I don't know how you do that. Can you have a look at my java file and tell me please? Thank You

Comment: You should share the code at SO as you never know when the link to the code will stop working in future

Comment: Ok I will do that in the future. Can you help please?

Comment: Edit the question and share the code here and then we can have a look here. Also you should have a look at @Tunaki comment.

Comment: This isn't a site where you get others to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for people to do my homework, I'm asking for help on how you do it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any code to accept the file passed with the < operator. As Majora320 wrote, the < operator renders the file to the standard input. In other wrods, your application will read the commands from the file as if it would have been entered from the keyboard.

The problem is with the scan.nextLine() call. This reads a whole line, and that makes impossible processing commands with parameter, e.g. **forward 10** since you read in the whole line, not only the command.

The example below reads first a string (in.next()), and may continue with reading the parameter (in.nextInt()) if a command is expected to have a parameter. But it does not read any parameters for the **stop** command.

```
public class Robot {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            final String command=in.next();

            if (command.equals("forward")) {
                final int distance=in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Forwarding "+distance);
            }

            if (command.equals("stop")) {
                System.out.println("Stopping");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The other little problem is that you're keep on reading the input until getting a **stop** command. This means that command files with no ending stop will not stop your application. It is safer to read until there is something to read, i.e. use while (in.hasNext()) to keep on reading.

Note how indentation and empty lines makes the code more readable, and much easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operator (At least on the *nix terminal) is for passing the text from a file into the stranded input of a program. For example, `grep "hello" < myfile.txt` is exactly the same as `cat myfile.txt | grep "hello"`. Basically, `<` is an abbreviation for running cat *file* | *command*. So what `java ConsoleRobot < commands_in_english.txt` means is pass all the lines in `commands_in_english.txt` to the stranded input of the `ConsoleRobot` program. That means you just write the instructions to the file and then run the command.

Comment: So you mean it is displayed as options from what commands to choose from? How do I write that up in code? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *show you how*? You type all the commands you want to execute into the file, one on each line, and run `java ConsoleRobot < commands_in_english.txt`. (Or `commands_in_spanish.txt`)

Comment: @Tom Oh, and there is no need to extend `SmarterRobot` - consider *is*-a vs *has*-a.